# Building pywt on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pywt

I have problems building pywt from source on Ubuntu.

When I run `python setup.py build`, I get the following error:

```
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
Cython is not installed. Using compiled file: src/_pywt.pyx
building 'pywt._pywt' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall    -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPY_EXTENSION -Isrc -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c src/_pywt.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/_pywt.o
gcc: error: src/_pywt.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4
```

When I run `cython --version` I get the following output:

```
Cython version 0.21.1
```

Comment: Did you know that `pywt` is already available as an [Ubuntu package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python-pywt)?

Answer (score 0):

pywt can be installed as an Ubuntu package using apt-get:

`sudo apt-get install python-pywt`